# Reading Kafka topic and writing to s3 using kafka connector

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-kafka, s3-kafka-connector

I have the following dataframe schema

```
root
 |-- sentence: string (nullable = true)
 |-- category: string (nullable = true)
```

I am writing the above dataframe successfully into a kafka topic(s3.topic). Next I want to read s3.topic from kafka and store the data in s3 bucket. For this I am using kafka connector. I have made the following config changes in the connect-distributed.properties file

```
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false
```

Following is the curl command I use to write into s3 bucket

```
curl -X POST \
   localhost:8084/connectors \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "name": "S3SinkConnector",
  "config": {
   "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector",
  "s3.region": "<region>",
  "flush.size": "1000",
  "topics": "s3.topic",
  "tasks.max": "1",
  "aws.secret.access.key": "<key>",
  "format.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat",
  "aws.access.key.id": "<keyId>",
  "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
  "storage.class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage",
  "s3.bucket.name": "<s3_bucket_name>",
  "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter"
  }
}'
```

And I am getting the following error

> ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=S3SinkConnector904-0} Error converting message
> value in topic 'emoji.analysis009' partition 0 at offset 0 and
> timestamp 1617585788233: JsonConverter with schemas.enable requires
> "schema" and "payload" fields and may not contain additional fields.
> If you are trying to deserialize plain JSON data, set
> schemas.enable=false in your converter configuration.
> (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:547)
> org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: JsonConverter with
> schemas.enable requires "schema" and "payload" fields and may not
> contain additional fields. If you are trying to deserialize plain JSON
> data, set schemas.enable=false in your converter configuration.
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.toConnectData(JsonConverter.java:370)
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.toConnectData(Converter.java:87)
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertValue(WorkerSinkTask.java:545)
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$1(WorkerSinkTask.java:501)
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:156)
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:190)
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:132)
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:501)
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:478)
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:328)
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:232)
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:201)
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:185)
> at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:234)
> at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

How can i write my topic data into s3 bucket with the printschema shown above?

UPDATE

Following is the printSchema() output of the dataframe written into kafka topic

```
root
 |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Error doesn't match your config. Somewhere you've set `schemas.enable=true`. Note: this connector schema config doesn't mean Spark schema... Have you tried using StringConverter with the JsonFormat?

Comment: @OneCricketeer can you point me to an example how to define the schema and payload as mentioned in the error rather than disabling the schema

Comment: S3 sink doesn't need a schema unless you want to write in Avro or Parquet, but if you want to do that, you might as well skip Kafka Connect altogether and write the stream using Spark. You can search the error message and find the information you're looking for, but start here maybe https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained/#json-schemas